# Creating string based on first letters of each element of the list

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

Example:

```
list = [abcc, typpaw, gfssdwww]
expected result = atgbyfcpscpsadwwww
```

Any ideas?

This is what i made so far:

```
def lazy_scribe(sources: list):
    result: str = ''
    i = 0
    while i < len(max(sources, key=len)):
        for source in sources:
            for char in source:
                if i <= len(source):
                    result = result + source[int(i)]
                else:
                    continue
                i += 1 / (len(sources))
                break
    return result


sources = ["python", "java", "golang"]
print(lazy_scribe(sources))
print(len(sources))
```

result: "pjgyaoyvlhaaononngn". I dont know why there is "y" instead of t (7 char in result string)

Comment: You should supply some code that you wrote in order to solve the problem, and the problems you have with it. refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, this should work.

```
list = ["abcc", "typpaw", "gfssdwww"]

max_len = len(max(list, key=len))

res = ""
char_iterator = 0

while char_iterator < max_len:
    for word in list:
        if char_iterator < len(word):
            res += word[char_iterator]
    char_iterator += 1

print(res)
```

Comment: And if I have a result: "pjgyaotvlhaaonng" is there an easy way to replace multiplied chars with its amount? Example: ""pjgyaotvlhaaonng" >> "pjgyaotvlh2ao2ng"

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is as follows:

```
l = ['abcc', 'typpaw', 'gfssdwww']
max_len = len(max(l, key=len))
padded_l = list(zip(*[e + " " * (max_len - len(e)) for e in l]))
''.join([''.join(e) for e in padded_l]).replace(' ', '')
```

1. find the longest string in the list
2. then pad all the strings in the list with blank space
3. use [`zip`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) on the result list
4. join the elements and replace the blank space to get the desired result

Comment: nice trick (normalizing strings all of the same length)!